# Copy text value and formatting to another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, format

I have to call the text value of cell A1 using index+match function to A2.

A1 contains two fonts – Calibri (11) and Times New Roman (20). I want to get the same text format in cell A2.

How can I do that without VBA?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy and paste format, or if there's a specific value you want to associate with that text format, you can use conditional formatting. Anything else, you'll need VBA.